# "Type Error":"Failed to fetch error", after sending form data to googlesheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch, google-sheets-api

After form submit the data was sent to googlesheet. But same time it throws typeerror:"failed to fetch". I am getting the same error even after I used axios.so the next line after fetch is not running. The code stops working after fetch call.

Below one is the  code pasted in googlesheet appscript.

```
const sheetName = 'Sheet1'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

below code is formsubmit function

```
 try {
                let inputValue = {
                    Name: create.Name,
                    Phone: create.Phone,
                    Email: create.Email,
                    Date: currentDate.toDateString(),
                };
                let form_data = new FormData();
                for (let key in inputValue) {
                    form_data.append(key, inputValue[key]);
                }
                const response = await fetch(
                    "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyvB7lH3htoX4NkyzqQ4zC_lqBCXWSso_g7P6_nZ55FtMgCXKlInz0AQIbP2IBF9abqpA/exec", 
                    {
                      method: "POST",
                      body: form_data,
                    }
                  );
                  console.log("rese",response)

            } catch (error) {
                setLoading(false)
                console.error("Error writing to Google Sheets:", error);
            }
```